# Ruby - Writing big files into SQLITE Database needs more speed

Tags: ruby, performance, sqlite

My company has lots of very big files; Textfiles, CVS tables and so forth.
I want to write a program that reads all the contents from the file, line by line and writes it into a SQLite Database.

The program works exactly like it should, but it is too slow.
It writes 50.000 Entries in almost 2 Minutes.
But the files it have to deal with, if I will use it in production, have over 10.000.000 entries. Some of them twice as much.

Which means I need to speed things up.

Here is the program:

```ruby
require 'sqlite3'
require 'benchmark'
system("clear")


    db = SQLite3::Database.open "./database/BenchmarkBase.db"
    counter = 0
      bench = Benchmark.measure {


          theFile = File.open("/root/Downloads/test/cellphoneNumbers.txt", 'r').each do |line|
            begin
              db.execute "INSERT INTO PhoneN(cellPhone) VALUES ('#{line}')"
              print "Entry: "
              print counter += 1
              print " .. has been written into database." + "\r"


            rescue SQLite3::Exception => e

              puts "Exception occurred"
              puts e

            end
          end

      }
    puts "time consumption: #{bench.real}"
    db.close if db
```

Forking this process have literally no performance boost. (or maybe I did it wrong.)
so if anyone has a good idea how I can make the progress faster, please don't hesitate to tell me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The biggest thing is using transactions that encompass multiple inserts. Some good reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite (just ignore the C API specific bits or figure out how they map to Ruby's bindings).

Comment: I would argue that SQLite might not be the best choice when it comes to SQL database engines for production load. Did you consider PostgreSQL or MySQL for your production environment?

Comment: @Shawn you killing me.. 50k inserts in 6 milliseconds. Thank you for that awesome guide!